I am running oracle23c on Oracle Linux 8.8. When I run dnf, I get the following error. What is the solution to this?
I am running oracle23c on Oracle Linux 8.8.
When I run dnf, I get the following error. I tried dnf update --skip-broken --nobest but no luck.
What is the solution to this?
Last metadata expiration check: 0:25:07 ago on Thu 09 May 2024 05:38:31 PM IST.
Error:
 Problem: package oracle-database-free-23c-1.0-1.x86_64 from @System requires oracle-database-preinstall-23c, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package oracle-database-preinstall-23ai-1.0-2.el8.x86_64 from ol8_appstream obsoletes oracle-database-preinstall-23c provided by oracle-database-preinstall-23c-1.0-1.el8.x86_64 from @System
  - package oracle-database-preinstall-23ai-1.0-2.el8.x86_64 from ol8_appstream obsoletes oracle-database-preinstall-23c provided by oracle-database-preinstall-23c-1.0-0.5.el8.x86_64 from ol8_developer
  - package oracle-database-preinstall-23ai-1.0-2.el8.x86_64 from ol8_appstream obsoletes oracle-database-preinstall-23c provided by oracle-database-preinstall-23c-1.0-1.el8.x86_64 from ol8_developer
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package oracle-database-preinstall-23c-1.0-1.el8.x86_64
  - problem with installed package oracle-database-free-23c-1.0-1.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

